# IronPython set property value on creating instance (Like c#)

Tags: c#, .net, ironpython

Does IronPython supports, to set a property value on creating a new instace.

In C# it is possible:

```
SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter() { Value = "123", ... };
```

Is there a syntax element for this in IronPython?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. IronPython [supports keyword arguments in constructor calls](http://ironpython.net/documentation/dotnet/dotnet.html#instantiating-net-types), and these will be mapped to property assignments:

```
param = SqlParameter(Value = "123", ...)
```